# BlackBerry: Turning on Wifi in code

Tags: blackberry, wifi

Is there a way to enable Wifi from code in BlackBerry OS?

Thx

-- EDIT --

I just wanted to add the code snippet for checking if WiFi is already enabled:

```
if ( (RadioInfo.getActiveWAFs() & RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN) == RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN ) { 
    // do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`Radio.activateWAFs()`](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/system/Radio.html#activateWAFs%28int%29) method to do this, if you pass [`WAF_WLAN`](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html) as a parameter. You can use it to enable or disable each wireless connection on the device.

Answer (score 6):

`Radio.deactivateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN);`

`Radio.activateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN);`